# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: стилистика

"Однако эксперты полагают, что причины сближения России с Китаем и Индией в космической сфере пока только политические, технологически этим странам предложить нам нечего."

Возник вопрос. Россия ничего не может предложить этим странам или этим странам нечего предложить России?

Comment: @Lioness, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

(технологически = в технологическом отношении) этим странам предложить нам нечего

Если мы не знаем, чьи технологии привлекательны настолько, что их можно предложить, то одинаково естественно выглядят оба взаимоисключающих смысла. Нужный смысл можно выразить более однозначно простой перестановкой слов. Один из смыслов становится гораздо естественнее другого (этот другой становится возможным только в устной форме, когда говорящий "зарапортовался" - ему ещё и объясняться придётся).

1. (Технологически) нам нечего предложить этим странам (так может понять тот, кто не знает, чьи технологии совершеннее)
2. (Технологически) этим странам нечего предложить нам (нужный смысл)

Answer (score 0):

Смысл такой: Китаю и Индии предложить нам нечего.

Разберем предложение: технологически этим странам (пауза) предложить нам нечего.

Грамматика: предложение односоставное, главный член "нечего предложить" , обстоятельство "технологически" и два дополнения (этим странам и нам), семантическую роль которых надо выяснить.

А выясняется это при актуальном членении предложения, которое проводит раздел между сочетаниями: этим странам - предложить нам.

Другое прочтение, другой смысл: технологически нам (пауза) этим странам предложить нечего.